# Dumping function into a dynamical assembly

Tags: c#, dll, decision-tree, accord.net

I am trying to learn how to use Accord framework to work with decision trees in c#. I am following this tutorial: [LINK](http://crsouza.blogspot.sk/2012/01/decision-trees-in-c.html). So far I understand how it works, but I am stuck after learning and compiling the tree. I am using the exact same code as in the tutorial so I am here:

```
  // Convert to an expression tree
  var expression = tree.ToExpression();

  // Compiles the expression to IL
  var func = expression.Compile();
```

Now I would like to know how to access this function (it is also in the tutorial).

```
 public static int Compute(double[] input)
```

This function is somehow generated. In the tutorial, there is also a link on how to dump a function into a dynamicall assembly, but I am not sure how to use it. Here is the code:

```
 var da = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
new AssemblyName("dyn"), // call it whatever you want
AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

var dm = da.DefineDynamicModule("dyn_mod", "dyn.dll");
var dt = dm.DefineType("dyn_type");
var method = dt.DefineMethod(
"Foo", 
MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

lambda.CompileToMethod(method);
dt.CreateType();

da.Save("dyn.dll");
```

Can someone help me please with this? Thank you.

EDIT: How to pass test data and obtain result from learned tree? That is my question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. `Compile` returns delegate that you can invoke via something like `var result = func(arg)` (its not clear to me what the delegate type is). I think that link to generating a dynamic assembly is trying to explain how to look at the underlying generated code. Probably not something a user would do normally unless you are trying to understand the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass test data and obtain the result from the learned tree, you can simply use [the tree's Compute method](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_Learning_ID3Learning.htm):

```
int output = tree.Compute(inputs);
```

In the context of the aforelinked example, you could use it like this in order to obtain the PlayTennis answer for a (Sunny, Hot, High, Strong) input:

```
// Convert the (Sunny, Hot, High, Strong) to a feature vector
double[] inputs = codebook.Translate("Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong");

// Compute the tree's output for the given feature vector
int output = tree.Compute(inputs);

// Convert the generated output into one of the problem's outcomes:
string answer = codebook.Translate("PlayTennis", y);
```

It is not necessary to compile/generate a new assembly in order to use the tree. This functionality can be used when absolute performance is required when evaluating new samples, such as in real-time applications.